# actor round robin pool and stopping strategy

Tags: akka, actor

I have actors with round robin pool of size 'n' each . So when app is started I initialize n number of actors in a pool and use them using ActorSystem actorSelection . Question is

Do we have to explicitly call context().stop(getSelf()); in each actor after its done doing the work ? 
As per my understanding if you call .stop() , next time you need an actor and pool actors are all consumed and as long as pool can accommodate creating a new actor it will create a new one and return the instance for processing. with that you would be spending cycles creating an actor and returning (in case of .stop()) vs simply returning from pool (in case of no explicit .stop())

Is my assumption correct ?.

Another question is As long as we are using round robin pool (or any other strategy ) there would always be "n" (e.g. 1000) of actors created and if there are more than "n" (e.g 1100) requests at a time , 100 requests are queued in a actors mailbox and processed as actors are freed up ? Can you confirm ?

-Thanks
R

Comment: Why do you want to stop the routees?  If you are all done with your work then stop the routeer and it will stop all its children.

Comment: @cmbaxter,  I have something like this on each actors public static Props props = Props.create(EventsProcessorActor.class).withRouter(new RoundRobinPool(100));  and there is another broker actor that is kicking off these actors as there is a new request for certain type of work. So when you say stop router , which piece of code are you talking about.  Moreover my question was if we are using round robin pool , is it required to stop actor explicitly ? doesn't base system takes care of cleaning up actors once its done doing the work (once it exits the execution context)